# C++ structure issue

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, graph-theory

What is the functionality of this part below?

```
bool operator < ( const edge& p ) const 
{
    return w < p.w;
}
```

I'm giving the Full code here(I don't know if it's necessary or not to paste the whole code). I just don't understand the structure part.
I've searched several resources but don't get any simplicity.

```
struct edge
{
    int u,v,w;
    bool operator < ( const edge& p ) const 
    {
        return w < p.w;
    }
};

int pr[MAXN];
vector<edge>e;

int find(int r)
{
    return (pr[r]==r) ? r:  find(pr[r]);
}

int mst(int n)
{
    sort(e.begin(),e.end());
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)pr[i]=i;

    int count=0,s=0;
    for(int i=0;i<(int)e.size();i++)
    {
        int u=find(e[i].u);
        int v=find(e[i].v);
        if(u!=v)
        {
            pr[u]=v;
            count++;
            s+=e[i].w;
            if(count==n-1) break;
        }
    }
    return s;
}

int main(){
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    for(int i=1;i<=m;i++)
    {
        int u,v,w;
        cin>>u>>v>>w;
        edge get;
        get.u=u; get.v=v; get.w=w;
        e.push_back(get);
    }
    cout<<mst(n)<<endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Which part of the definition of `struct edge` don't you understand?

Comment: *"Need explanation"* is not an actual question. Please [edit] your post to ask a specific question that actually has an answer.

Comment: Google "operator overloading".

Comment: A c++-structure is more like a c++-class than a c-structure.  Your struct has 3 integers.  The (non-virtual) method should not affect sizeof(edge).  There are also several methods that the compiler provides such as ctor and dtor and a few others (because you have not disallowed them), .

Comment: I don't understand  the operator overloading part from the structure.I haven't use it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about when you do `1 < 3`. 1 is obviously smaller than 3. Alright, but suppose you have this `struct`/`class`/`union` (note the 3 are almost the same thing in C++) called `Toy`:

```
struct Toy
{
  float _volume;
  float _weight;
  std::string _brand;
};
```

Now you instantiate 2 `Toy` objects:

```
Toy car, kite;
car._volume = 27000.0; //27000 cm^3
car._weight = 150.0; //150 grams

kite._volume = 10000; //10000 cm^3
kite._weight = 200.0; // 200 grams

if (kite < car){
  std::cout << "car!"; // is toy car bigger!?
}else{
  std::cout << "kite!"; // or is it the kite?
}
```

Now, there, the C++ language doesn't know what you mean when you check if the kite is `smaller` than the toy car. It could be either that you want to see which has less weight, or it could be that you're checking which takes less space; smaller in volume. To solve the ambiguity, C++ asks you the programmer to implement operators for your custom objects.

If we strip the `syntactic sugar` part of the design of many operators, let it be smaller than (`<`) for the sake of the example, `a < b` becomes `a.operator<(b)`. So `operator<` can be said to be a class/struct/union method like any other!

To clear the ambiguity in the toy example, we re-implement/overload our struct's `operator<()` method to let it compare volumes as follows:

```
struct Toy
{
  float _volume;
  float _weight;
  std::string _brand;
  bool operator<(const Toy & otherToy)
  {
    return _volume < otherToy._volume; // or ._weight for each if we want to compare by weight
  }
};

if (kite < car){
  std::cout << "car!"; // the car has more volume!
}else{
  std::cout << "kite!";
}
```

With your code snippet, you can see that an `edge` object comparison criterion was defined in operator< definition as the member `w`. So whichever has the smaller `w` is the smaller object when compared with that operator.

Comment: Yeah nice and simple explanation.I get it now Thanks @Aiman